# Trying to use Vim, in Ubuntu. Just showing "blank screen"

Tags: linux, terminal

I installed what I believe is the full version of Vim. I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://dan.van.derveer.com/twenty/category/arcade/) to save high scores on my Game Elf JAMMA board (not that this really matters to you). I'm on step 8 in the tutorial. I type in `vim /mnt/three/etc/init.d/rcs` and then [this is what shows up in my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FOZ3.jpg). The tutorial says I need to add a line after "System Starting" but I don't see any text at all.

Comment: As the status line indicates, it is a new file: there is nothing for Vim to display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `vim` is behaving as expected.  In your screenshot, it appears that you are trying to `vim /mnt/three/etc/init.d/rcs`, when the tutorial is calling for `vim /mnt/three/etc/init.d/rcS`.  Linux is not case-insensitive like windows, so `rcs` and `rcS` are two different files.

Comment: @KenyonGeetings if you have never used Vim before, run `vimtutor` to get a quick intro on how to use it. Or use `nano` instead.